# How to speed up computing in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to compute all the parameters of the cell in a matrix and then make a video by using colormap scatter function and videowriter. My code is fine but it is taking very long to compute when I am using higher values of n=64 and N=241.

```
%% Implementing time loop
for k=2:N
    for i=1:n
        for j=1:n
            cell(i,j,k).threshold=cell(i,j,k-1).threshold+(-H1*M/P+cell....
                (i,j,k-1).activity*(H1+H2*cell(i,j,k-1).input)/D)*0.25;
            cell(i,j,k).exc_level=cell(i,j,k-1).exc_level+....
                ((cell(i,j,k-1).input+cell(i,j,k-1).exc_level)/K)*0.25;
            if cell(i,j,k-1).activity==0 &&....
                    cell(i,j,k).exc_level>cell(i,j,k).threshold
                cell(i,j,k).activity=1;
            elseif cell(i,j,k-1).activity==1 && cell(i,j,k-6).activity==0
                cell(i,j,k).activity=1;
            else
                cell(i,j,k).activity=0;
            end;
        end;
    end;
    for i=1:n
        for j=1:n
            [Z_coord1,Z_coord2,Z_act,Z_exc]=dendrite5(cell,i,j,n,k);
            cell(i,j,k).input=sum(Z_act.*Z_exc);
        end;
    end;
end;
```

I want to compute this time loop for n=64 and N=241. Can you suggest me ways to speed up my code. Also I think the main problem lies in the function dendrite5. So here is the function:

```
function [Z_coord1,Z_coord2,Z_act,Z_exc]=dendrite5(cell,i_0,j_0,n,k)

Z_coord1=zeros(1,i_0+6);
Z_coord2=zeros(1,i_0+6);
Z_act=zeros(1,i_0+6);
Z_exc=zeros(1,i_0+6);

for i=i_0-6:i_0+6
    for j=j_0-6:j_0+6
        [i_hex_0,j_hex_0]=grid2hex(i_0,j_0);
        [i_hex,j_hex]=grid2hex(i,j);
        [i_card,j_card]=hex2card(i_hex,j_hex);
        [i_0_card,j_0_card]=hex2card(i_hex_0,j_hex_0);
        if (i_card-i_0_card)^2+(j_card-j_0_card)^2<1.70^2
            [i_centered,j_centered]=boundary2(i,j,n);
            d=sqrt((i_card-i_0_card)^2+(j_card-j_0_card)^2);
            w=(2*0.85^2*acos(d/(2*0.85))-0.5*sqrt(4*0.85^2-d^2))/pi*0.85^2;
            Z_coord1=[Z_coord1 i_centered];
            Z_coord2=[Z_coord2 j_centered];
            Z_act=[Z_act cell(i_centered,j_centered,k).activity];
            Z_exc=[Z_exc w];
        end;
    end;
end;
% Z_coord1=Z_coord1(Z_coord1~=0);
% Z_coord1=Z_coord1(Z_coord1~=0);
% Z_coord1=Z_coord1(Z_coord1~=0);
% Z_coord1=Z_coord1(Z_coord1~=0);
```

[Code formatted]

Answer (score 0):

Try to vectorize your code. MATLAB does not compile the code. It is an interpreter. Hence,

```
a = 1:1000000;
for i = a
   n = n+i;
end
```

is slower than

```
a = 1:1000000;
sum(a)
```

If you are really after speeding up you code, take a look at MEX files (http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/create-mex-files.html). They allow you to write and compile C and C++ code, compile it and run as Matlab functions, just like those fast built-in ones.

Comment: Actually, MATLAB does contain a just-in-time compiler (or JIT) - and sometimes it actually can be quicker to write the loop than use the vectorised method - but usually only for relatively simple loops involving arithmetic.

Answer (score 0):

Try initializing your variables outside the for loops.  That may help.

Specifically, look at your cell and your Z_coord.  I mention the last one because you are appending to the array when you do

```
Z_coord1 = [Z_coord1 i_center];
```

and thus it keeps growing.  Matlab slows down significantly if this becomes "too large."  The same statement applies to your cell variable (this is in 3 nexted for loops).  If you create them outside the for loop, the space already is allocated.

Comment: Can you guide me on how to pre-allocate them outside the for loop??